# Checked Checkbox opacity, rule is overriden even when declared after

Tags: css

I want to hide a checkbox by default and show a checkbox when it's selected, in the table-headd or the corresponding row is hovered:

```
.table td input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
}

.table th input[type=checkbox], 
.table tr:hover input[type=checkbox], 
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

When inspecting the result in Chrome Dev Tools, the second rule applies, but the opacity attribute is crossed out. I need to add an `!important` to get the desired result. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the specifity of CSS. You can give more specifity to the rule to make it more important without `!important` sentence:

```
.table td input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
}

.table th input[type=checkbox], 
.table tr:hover input[type=checkbox], 
.table tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

How specifity works?

- Inline style elements: 1000
- IDs: 100
- Tags: 10
- Classnames and attributes: 1

If you make the sum, you'll obtain the specifity. The more specifity it's the rule applied.

Comment: Since it is going after, there is no need for 'more' specifity, `.table td input[type=checkbox]:checked` is sufficient. Even if he specify it before, it would be applied, because of `:checked`. Classes, attributes **and pseudo-classes** should worth same, for example 2.

Comment: You're right, I only write that selector to show how specifity grows

Comment: This is a bit misleading. These don't really have a value as stated. If you have 11 tags, it doesn't add up to 110 and override a single ID. These work in orders of magnitude, so in other words, a single ID will always take precedence over any number of classnames, and an ID will never override an inline style.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use !important if you do an assigment as specific as the first one, so instead `input[type=checkbox]:checked` use `.table td input[type=checkbox]:checked`, this way css will apply the second rule, because it is as specific as the first rule:

```
.table td input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity: 0;
}

.table th input[type=checkbox], 
.table tr:hover input[type=checkbox], 
.table td input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
.table td input[type=checkbox]
```

has more **[specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** than

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked
```

Specificity counts for more than the vertical order in which your rules are declared, hence the first rule wins out.